# Detecting how many items are enabled

Tags: vba

In my program l am using timers to make pictureboxes visible and after certain time l make them not visible by using picturebox(1-9).visible = true/false.

Finally l have to count how many pictureboxes are visible at any given time.

l can't figure it out l have tried adding them to a variable but the timer does it over and over every second. l have literally no idea how to do it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are your picture boxes in Access? What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Every you time you change the visibility of a `PictureBox` change the value of a `NumberVisible` variable.  If you just hid a `PictureBox`, subtract 1 from `NumberVisible`.  If you just showed a `PictureBox`, add 1 to the value of `NumberVisible`.  You will need to know how many are visible before you start the timer, but that is as easy as checking the visibility property of each `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is for Images on a worksheet, but can easily be modified for wherever your pictureboxes are:

```
'Count the visible number before starting.
Dim NumberVisible As Integer
NumberVisible = 0
For i = 1 To 9
    If myWorkSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue Then
        NumberVisible = NumberVisible + 1
    End If
Next

'....
'Start timer, do timer code here.
'....
myWorkSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoTrue
NumberVisible = NumberVisible + 1

'...
myWorkSheet.Shapes(i).Visible = msoFalse
NumberVisible = NumberVisible - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `picturebox(1-9).visible` itself. The same variable can be set and can also be checked for a given value.

Just loop through all the picture boxes in the form and check their visible property.

```
Sub foo()

Dim ct As Control
Dim sum As Integer
sum = 0

For Each ct In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(ct) = "Image" Then
        If ct.Visible = False Then
            sum = sum + 1
        End If
    End If

Next

MsgBox sum

End Sub
```